# How to implement bouncing in scrollview?

Tags: android

I have implement simple one simple database application in which I have used scrollview.Its work fine.But scrollview is not bounce.

Is it possible to enable bounce in scrollview?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to give it a Iphone like effect? Better if you dont. Try to use default Android functionality. you can make use of animations try this link  [http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: I don't really know how to do this, I'm just thinking of how I would approach this...

Have you tried to put empty space on both ends of the view? That way it would look like the user is scrolling past the beginning/end. If there's a listener involved maybe you could test to see if the user is in the 0-10% range or the 90-100% range, and if so, "bounce" them back?\

Edit: I found this article: [Support Bounce Property for Scrollview in Android](http://www.techhui.com/group/android/forum/topics/support-bounce-property-for)